# Why does the span tag not work with my css in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

Why does my CSS not work when I use a span tag in React, but when I change it to a div it shows up?

Here my normal HTML code:

```html
<div class="menu-toggle" id="mobile-menu">
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
</div>
```

Here is my React code:

```html
<div className="menu-toggle mobile-menu">
  <span className="bar"></span>
  <span className="bar"></span>
  <span className="bar"></span>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS I'm using to target the code:

```css
.menu-toggle .bar {
  width: 25px;
  height: 3px;
  margin: 5px auto;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
}
```

So if I change all the `span` tags to `div` tags in React, my code works completely fine, but with `span` it doesn't. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

this is maybe because of the other css that implies on the span tag. can you change the  `.menu-toggle .bar`  selector to `#mobile-menu .bar` to see if it works?

ps. dont forget to add mobile-menu id to your react code!

Comment: whenever I tried to target a react jsx with an id it didn't work. Do I simply just put id="name" in my jsx? because  I know class has to be className but I couldn't find anything for id

Comment: I tried to add the id and target that one but still doesn't do anything

Comment: can you provide a screen shot from your inspect element? or a link?

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block` and it should work

```
.menu-toggle .bar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    background: #fff; 
    color: #fff; 
    display: block;
}
```